# Understanding dispatch_sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Please consider following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        for (int i; i < 100 ; i++) {

            NSLog(@"%i", i);

        }

    });

    NSLog(@"Main thread code");

}
```

Why its only output is - `2016-01-26 16:15:28.842 Test[1051:35933] Main thread code`
?

I mean, code in global queue is never executed, why? I only want it to execute synchronously. Of course i could easy write `dispatch_async`, but im just curious why code above not work, does not output anything execept `2016-01-26 16:15:28.842 Test[1051:35933] Main thread code`?

Comment: works fine for me... I think your problem is elsewhere

Comment: @originaluser2 i paste that code in empty project, i created for testing purpose.

Comment: I also pasted the code into an empty project, and it worked! Although it's also worth mentioning that this code makes no sense. This will block the main thread until something on a background thread has completed... why not just run it on the main thread in that case? You should be using `dispatch_async` for this.

Comment: @originaluser2 i write this code for learning purpose only, and that code not block main thread, because main thread NSLog output fine..

Comment: no, I mean it blocks the main thread *while* it is running. Once it's finished running, the main thread will continue. Also, try using `%d` as your string formatting option. Not sure what `%i` is.

Comment: @originaluser2 %i stand for integer. I still dont understand why its not output anything for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101679/discussion-between-originaluser2-and-evgeniy-kleban).

Comment: problem is in 
     
    for (int i; i < 100 ; i++)   

u r not initialise value of i , 
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in

```
for (int i; i < 100 ; i++)
```

for above code value of i = 72339625 so condition not satisfied and not goes into loop

solution : initialise value of i ,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
```